# Heroku MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, heroku

I (cannot) run my application on Heroku. It works fine on a local run but cloud. I do not understand the real reason.

- Cloud mongodb cluster
- Spring Boot app on Heroku

**application.properties:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://demo-user:demo@demo-******u.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=60000&connectTimeoutMS=60000
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
```

**Heroku Console Log:**

```
2019-09-09T14:56:51.741370+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-09-09 14:56:51.741  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@7d9d0818 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=demo-carp*****u.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, ServerDescription{address=demo-carpool-shard-00-00-hrjju.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, ServerDescription{address=demo-ca*****rjju.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]}. Waiting for 60000 ms before timing out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with the Mongodb Cloud Network Access setup.
There is a concept called 'whitelist'. My home's ip address was added there but the cloud server's. I had to add the server's ip address either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both the home IP address and the server's IP address. Plus the cluster's name is Case sensitive. This is too can cause errors